Acoustic diffraction grating
Is it possible for diffraction grating to make similar scattering pattern as how it can for light?
If no please say why in detail

Googling "acoustic diffraction grating" yields various sources to consult. Note some overloading with acoustically constructed optical diffraction volumes of liquid.

The stepped seating in a stadium makes one.
